# Vimscript: regex works in :s but not in substitute()

Tags: regex, variables, vim

If I paste the output of :ls into a buffer, the command

```
:%s/.*\(\".*\"\).*/\1/
```

reduces that output to just the file paths. Wanting to achieve that result in a variable, I did

```
:redir => x|silent :ls|redir END
:let y = substitute(x, ".*\(\".*\"\).*", "\1", "g")
```

which accomplished absolutely nothing, y is identical to x. I've tried umpteen variations on that substitute command, getting only the same result, or a bunch of error messages. How should I be specifying it?

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape backslashes in quotes. Use `\\(` and `\\\"` with `substitute()`.

Comment: It's less to do with using `substitute()` and more to do with using a double-quoted string.  Using single-quotes would help avoid a lot of that escaping.  Compare `:help expr-string` to `:help literal-string`.

Comment: Indeed, single quotes work best for situations like these. Same for the `\1` in the second argument.

Comment: Thank you, I was following the examples for substitute() which both use ".  But there is still a problem.  The only output delivered is the last occurrence of the pattern.  It doesn't seem to be that the let occurs with each line matched, but that only the final match is delivered.  I did :let y = substitute(x, '.*\(".*"\).*', '\1', "g") and then :let y = y . substitute(x, '.*\(".*"\).*', '\1', "g") and the only change was that the last match output was duplicated by the second version

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors: first was already mentioned by @Radu, second is arises from the fact that in `substitute()` newline matches `.`, while in `:s` it is not. That is why «only the final match is delivered». I can post a correct solution using `:redir`, `:ls` and `substitute()`, but instead suggest the following:

```
let buflist=map(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)'), 'bufname(v:val)')
```

If you want output almost identical to what `:ls` has, try replacing `bufname(v:val)` with `BufName(v:val)`:

```
function BufName(bnr)
    let bn=bufname(a:bnr)
    let bt=getbufvar(a:bnr, '&buftype')
    if empty(bn)
        return (empty(bt)?('[No Name]'):('[Scratch]'))
    elseif empty(bt)
        " This won't produce names like ../file, while :ls will "
        return fnamemodify(bn, ':~:.')
    elseif bt is# 'help'
        return fnamemodify(bn, ':t')
    else
        return bn
    endif
endfunction
```

The above command leaves you with a list of strings. If you want to have a newline-separated «list» instead, use

```
let bufliststr=join(buflist, "\n")
```

If you still want to use `substitute()`, see `:h /[]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I do want to use substitute, because if I don't get this peculiarity of its usage resolved now, I'll be having the same problem with it again in the near future.  So let me check out :h /[] and see if I can resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The variable x contains

```
1 #    "~/Session.vim"                line 5
2      "~/.vimrc"                     line 34
3      ".vim/vscripts/makesess.vim"   line 4
4      "~/Documents/vimcht"           line 62
5      "~/.fluxbox/startup"           line 5
6      "~/Documents/Notes"            line 2604
7      "~/Documents/bashcht"          line 21
8 %a   "junk"                         line 10
```

By my reading of :h /[], particularly "...Without the "_" or "\n" the collection does not match an end-of-line...", then

```
:let y = ""
:let y = substitute(x, '[.]*\("[.]*"\)[.]*', '\1', "g")
```

should have done the job.  But it delivered

```
"junk"
```

just as it did without the []. 
I then tried

```
:let y = ""
:let y = substitute(x, '[^\n]*\("[^\n]*"\)[^\n]*', '\1', "g")
```

and got exactly the same result.

Clearly vim does not use the actual newline character internally, neither for variables nor for registers.  So it treats a variable as a single line.  Which led me to this solution

```
:let y = substitute(x, '[^"]*\("[^"]\+"\)[^"]*', ':tabe \1\n', 'g')
```

yielding y containing

```
:tabe "~/Session.vim"
:tabe "~/.vimrc"
:tabe ".vim/vscripts/makesess.vim"
:tabe "~/Documents/vimcht"
:tabe "~/.fluxbox/startup"
:tabe "~/Documents/Notes"
:tabe "~/Documents/bashcht"
:tabe "junk"
```

as desired to form my Session.vim file

Comment: I guess it will be surprising, but `[^\n]` would be normal solution... if you have used double quotes. As stated in help, `\n` inside a collection unconditionally **adds** newline to the list of characters matched by collection and thus `[^\n]` will match everything including newline. With double quotes it will be translated to actual newline. Another variant is using `[^\x0A]`. By the way, `tabe "~/Session.vim"` will open a new empty buffer as `"` starts the comment.

Comment: And «vim does not use the actual newline character internally» is false. It uses it, but internally lines are represented as a list of NULL-terminated strings with actual newline used to represent NULL in the file. Inside the registers things are more complicated, but for strings `substitute()` thinks that newline is a NULL representation, not line terminator. See `:h NL-used-for-Nul`.

Comment: Third problem is that you are not escaping file names in case they contain spaces. With my solution it would be `let seslines=map(copy(buflist), '"tabedit ".fnameescape(v:val)')` and you can append these lines to Session.vim file using `call writefile(readfile($HOME.'/Session.vim', 'b')+seslines, $HOME.'/Session.vim', 'b')`.

Comment: Fourth: dot is not special inside a collection. `[.]` will match only a dot, not any character.

Comment: Fifth: `\n` in replacement string (third argument to `substitute()`, second for `:s`) emits NULL, not NL. Newline will be represented as `\r` here (see `:h s/\r` and a line above it). In this case it does not matter: NULL will be represented as NL, but it may be a surprise if you write this in `:s`.

Comment: Many thanks Zyx, particularly about vim's internal representation and the specific :h references.  I appreciate your solution as how-this-problem-should-be-solved, but at present it goes over my head.  Being lazy, I won't learn anything until I have to.  So I did find vim will only write files from a list, and the effect of those "s inherited from :ls.  I never use spaces in file paths, so my working solution is :redir => x|silent :ls|redir END 
:let ylist = eval('[' . substitute(x, '[^"]*"\([^"]\+\)"[^"]*', '":tabe \1", ', 'g') . '""]')
:call writefile(ylist, "/home/g/Session.vim", "")